# What is "Application startup file" option on Cpanel python application?

Tags: python, django, deployment, server, cpanel

I'm trying to deploy my django project to my host using cpanel, but there are some new options in Create python applications tab. What should i set for the following items:

"Application startup file"

"Application Entry point"

[create application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnTfT.png)

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Mentioning who your hosting is / was would have been helpful here. I use NameCheap and am wondering if this advise would work for me.

Comment: If your host provides cpanel for management and cpanel is updated this would work for you. My provider is a local one which uses cpanel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok it's actually pretty simple. When you want to deploy your Django app to cpanel, these field should be filled with:

Application startup file = Address of Manage.py file to start your app.

Application Entry point = Address of wsgi.py in your project folder.

Comment: Not entirely related but do you know what these files would be for a Flask app? Thanks.

Comment: @Panpaper There is no difference actually set your "Application startup file" to your flask app startup file like main.py and "application entry point" is your app name which is going to be called on passenger_wsgi.py.